# Is there a way to add a some transaction message to the dot transfer?

Tags: polkadot-js

Example: If we are doing 10DOT Transfer from one address to another address, Can we attach some description like "test transaction" or "investment"?

Answer (score 4):

The `balances::transfer` did not provide a field for this.

But I think you could do this with `utility::batch`.

Call data:

```
0x1a000800012c54697020666f72204761760500006af08f6bb841825b168ddf79837e70d88d75e1c5b290b74fa97cedfd668dd22c0700e40b5402
```

You could decode the call data [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode).

Here is the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/utility/README.md).

In this case, `batch` combines the two calls into one.

What the `system::remark` does is left a message on the chain.

Comment: Can you provide code reference or docs or in-depth docs to understand?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Can you provide js or your preferred language code if possible for above example?.